# Load large Bitmap efficiently for dynamic image pick from gallery?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to load large Bitmap image in the Imageview.I am follow the code from [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) .It's shown for single imageView.But I want to pick images from gallery for dynamic ImageView.I try to get the id of the picked Image and set decodeSampledBitmapFromResouce.It's set the Empty in the ImageView.Please help me to solve the Issue.Any help I'm very appreciated.Please see my code Below.

```
Button loadImg;
ImageView myImageView;
InputStream imageStream;
Bitmap productIndex = null;

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPickImage);
    myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImgView);

    loadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImgView);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
        String imageType = options.outMimeType;

// here I set the bitmap to ImageView but the Image is not shown 
        int picId = getResources().getIdentifier(picturePath, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),picId,100,100));

    }
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,int reqWidth,int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;

    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth && (halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }

    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,int resId,int reqWidth,int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,resId,options);

    /* Calculate inSampleSize */
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,reqWidth,reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,resId,options);
}
```

Comment: Your image is from file rather than from resource, right?

Comment: @vincentzhou Yes, `myImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),picId,100,100));` Here picId I try to get the id of picked image.I think this is not correct ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(File f, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH
    String path = f.getAbsolutePath();

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    // Raw height and width of background
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    }

    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    // Correct rotation
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    if (rotation != 0f) {
        matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
    }

    Bitmap output = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    if (output != null) {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(output, 0, 0, output.getWidth(), output.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        return 90;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        return 180;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: bro `exifToDegrees(rotation)` makes error. `exifToDegrees` Cannot resolve method error ..